# Android SQLite query issue

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cursor

I am learning how to uses databases on Android and i am trying a simple example in which i have two textboxes [brakes and rpm] when i enter values into those boxes and hit the "write button" it enters them into the database table "performance". When i hit the "read" button it should query the table and print the contents but i get the following error while querying:

android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 re
quested, with a size of 0

Here is my relevant code:

```
private static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_BRAKES = "brakes";
private static final String KEY_RPM="rpm";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB2";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "performance";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table performance (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + "brakes text not null, rpm text not null);";


    //--insert an entry to the database--
public void insertData(String filter, String data){
    ContentValues entry = new ContentValues();

    if(filter.equals("b")){
        entry.put(KEY_BRAKES, data);
        Log.d(TAG,"inserted brake data");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, entry);
    }
    else if (filter.equals("r")){
        entry.put(KEY_RPM, data);
        Log.d(TAG,"inserted rpm data");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, entry);
    }


}

    //--retrive all entries
public Cursor getAllData(){
    Log.d(TAG,"about to query");
    try{
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_BRAKES,KEY_RPM}, null, null, null, null, null);
    Log.d(TAG,"id=" + c.getString(0));

    return c;
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d (TAG,"error");
        Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}
```

And the way that i enter items is as follows:

```
brakeRead = brakes.getText().toString();
rpmRead = brakes.getText().toString();
db.open();
db.insertData("b", brakeRead);
db.insertData("r", rpmRead);
db.close();
```

And the way i query is as follows:

```
                db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getAllData();
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do{
                    output.append("id: " +  c.getString(0) + " brakes: " + c.getString(1) + " rpm: " + c.getString(2));
                }while(c.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();
```

But i am getting this error while querying: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 re
quested, with a size of 0

Can anyone see if i am doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you calling getWritableDatabase/getReadableDatabase method call of SQLLiteOpenHelper somewhere?

Comment: in my open() function i am calling db =DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
but i am not calling getReadableDatabase anywhere am i supposed to? if so where would i need to call this?

Comment: Please have a look on answer of this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122337/sqlite-database-issue/7122577#comment-8535528) getWritableDatabase should be called in background thread...otherwise you might be trying to access database when your database is not completely created. And no you not need to use getReadableDatabase...where you are calling either of the method.

Comment: And can you please post your stacktrace, which will help in finding exact line for error..

Comment: I looked at that thread, I added a getReadable() before i query and i even did a Thread.sleep(1000); before i did the query but im having the same issue. The stack trace gave me this error: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 re quested, with a size of 0

Comment: My guess is: `Cursor`'s strings start from 1 (not 0).  If so, the error starts from here: `c.getString(0)`. It is a guess :)

Comment: i tried to start it from c.getString(1) and i still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query is perfect to retieve data but you got error as listed below it means you have no record in your database, so i think there is something missing while **inserting** database

**android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 re quested, with a size of 0**

Comment: no, i cant find any mistake but insist you to debug your code is it is inserting?

Comment: So i fixed the insert command and now it inserts properly (checked using sqlite browser) but i cannot read items i get this error now:

android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 re quested, with a size of 2

Comment: ok, now dnt use loop just check one record, move cursor to first position and print the value

Answer (score 0):

Change your Code from

```
if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do{
                    output.append("id: " +  c.getString(0) + " brakes: " + c.getString(1) + " rpm: " + c.getString(2));
                }while(c.moveToNext());
            }
```

to

```
            while(c.moveToNext()){
                output.append("id: " +  c.getString(0) + " brakes: " + c.getString(1) + " rpm: " + c.getString(2));
            }
```

**Update**

Your query is

```
Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_BRAKES,KEY_RPM}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

which is selecting two columns(BREAKS,RPM) .But you are querying for 3
change it to

```
Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_BRAKES,KEY_RPM}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: i now get this error after fixing the insert method:

android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 re quested, with a size of 2

Answer (score 0):

You have set both your brakes and rpm to not null, yet you are inserting data into each column one at a time. I would suggest rewriting insertData as follows:

```
public void insertData(String brakes, String rpm){
ContentValues entry = new ContentValues();

    entry.put(KEY_BRAKES, brakes);
    Log.d(TAG,"inserted brake data");

    entry.put(KEY_RPM, rpm);
    Log.d(TAG,"inserted rpm data");
    db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, entry);
}
```

You would then call it as such:

```
brakeRead = brakes.getText().toString();
rpmRead = brakes.getText().toString();
db.open();
db.insertData(brakeRead, rpmRead);
db.close();
```